# How to close WebViewClient on opening specified URL

Tags: c#, android, android-webview, xamarin

Right now I got a nested webviewclient class in a webpage class.

I override the **ShouldOverrideUrlLoading**, and make new urls load in my webview.
But on certain urls I just want to close the webview.

I tried adding it in the **ShouldOverrideUrlLoading** but I can not start/finish activities in there. I also tried to make a function inside the webpage class, but I failed to call it from the nested class.

Right now I just close the webview on pressing back, but I don't want the user to have to do that much work..

I use Xamarin(C#) to develop for Android, but a Java answer would most likely help aswell!

```
[Activity (Label = "WebPage", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
public class WebPage : Activity
{
    WebView web_view;

    private class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl (url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void dofinish()
    {
        var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
        activity2.PutExtra("targeturl", targeturl);
        StartActivity(activity2);

        Finish();
    }

    public string targeturl;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
        targeturl = Intent.GetStringExtra ("targeturl") ?? "No Target Url";

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.WebView);
        web_view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.LocalWebview);

        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.LoadUrl (text);
        web_view.SetWebViewClient (new HelloWebViewClient ());
    }

    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
        activity2.PutExtra("targeturl", targeturl);
        StartActivity(activity2);

        Finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: " I also tried to make a function inside the webpage class, but I failed to call it from the nested class." - Why so? What went wrong? Did it crash? If so where is the stack trace?

Comment: WebPage w = new WebPage (); w.dofinish();

Gives error: NullPointerException, on StartActivity.

http://pastebin.com/jsShjSR8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest passing a delegate into the `HelloWebViewClient` class that is used to close the web activity and bring the main activity back into focus.

To do this:

**1:** Declare a delegate type that will be used to close the web view activity:

```
 public delegate void OnLinkSelectedHandler(string url);
```

**2:** Create an implementation of `OnLinkSelectedHandler` within `WebPage` that will close the current activity and bring the `MainActivity` back into focus:

```
public void dofinish(string url)
{
    // Bring the other activity into focus.
    var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
    activity2.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    activity2.PutExtra("targeturl", url);
    StartActivity(activity2);

    // Close this activity.
    Finish();
}
```

Adding the additional flags `ActivityFlags.SingleTop` and `ActivityFlags.ClearTop` will cause the targetted activity to come back into focus without creating a new instance of it on the activity stack.

**3:** Implement the logic to invoke the delegate within the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` method in `HelloWebViewClient`:

```
public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
{
    view.LoadUrl (url);
    if (url == "http://stackoverflow.com/about")
    {
        this.linkSelected (url);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And when it is all brought together:

```
[Activity (Label = "WebPage", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
public class WebPage : Activity
{
    WebView web_view;

    public delegate void OnLinkSelectedHandler (string url);

    private class HelloWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private OnLinkSelectedHandler linkSelected;

        public HelloWebViewClient(OnLinkSelectedHandler handler)
        {
            linkSelected = handler;
        }

        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl (url);
            if (url == "http://stackoverflow.com/about")
            {
                this.linkSelected (url);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void dofinish(string url)
    {
        // Bring the other activity into focus.
        var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
        activity2.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        activity2.PutExtra("targeturl", url);
        StartActivity(activity2);

        // Close this activity.
        Finish();
    }

    public string targeturl;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.WebViewTest);
        web_view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webView1);

        web_view.LoadUrl ("http://stackoverflow.com");

        // Pass the callback used to close this activity.
        web_view.SetWebViewClient (new HelloWebViewClient (this.dofinish));
    }
}
```